# Azure function doesn't automatically load nuget assemblies

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have created nuget package with my custom assembly. It install just fine, but  the assemblies are not loaded by the function run time as it should according to the documentation

> When you upload a project.json file, the runtime gets the packages and
>   automatically adds references to the package assemblies. You don't
>   need to add #r "AssemblyName" directives. Just add the required using
>   statements to your run.csx file to use the types defined in the NuGet
>   packages.

Thus any using statement including namespaces from my package will just make the function unable to compile.

The assembly is targeting .net 4.6.1 is that a problem I can read that functions only support 4.6 in for the project json.

I can get the assembly to load if I reference it using #r "......\data\Functions\packages\nuget\letsencrypt.azure.core\0.6.16-prerelease\lib\net461\LetsEncrypt.SiteExtension.Core.dll"

This however just leads to all the other dependencies coming from nuget to also be missing. Can it really be true that I have to manually reference every single nuget for it to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out it is a problem if you target 4.6.1. It seems to be working now when I changed it to 4.6.